# Executing Powershell script on remote Windows EC2 instance in Terraform

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, terraform

I am starting a Windows EC2 instance in AWS. Now I want to install certain software like OpenSSH and some other tasks like creating user after the server has been created. If I have a PowerShell script, how do I execute on the remote instance?

I have a local PowerShell script - install_sft.ps1 and I want to execute on the remote EC2 instance in AWS.

I know I need to use a "provisioner" but unable to get my head around how to use it for Windows.

```
 resource "aws_instance" "win-master" {
  provider                    = aws.lmedba-dc
  ami                         = data.aws_ssm_parameter.WindowsAmi.value
  instance_type               = var.instance-type
  key_name                    = "RPNVirginia"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.windows-sg.id]
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.dc1.id
  tags = {
    Name = "Win server"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_main_route_table_association.set-master-default-rt-assoc]

}
```

Comment: `how do I execute on the remote instance?` First step is to enable PS remoting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making use of the `user_data` parameter of the `aws_instance` resource:

```
resource "aws_instance" "win-master" {
  ...
  user_data_base64 = "${base64encode(file(install_sft.ps1))}"
  ...
}
```

Just ensure that `install_sft.ps1` is in the same directory as your Terraform code.

An EC2 instance's User Data script executes when it starts up for the first time. [See the AWS documentation here for more details.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html)

Comment: Do we really need to base64encode if we are setting it to `user_data`? there is another property `user_data_base64` that is specific to  base64?

Comment: You are correct - I have updated the answer above. Thanks!